# Free Chinese Named Entity Datasets or Free Chinese NER System

Tags: entity, nlp, cjk

I want to use Stanford NER system as a NLP tool in my work. However it lacks a classifier model for Chinese Named Entity. I must train the model by myself. I did not find any free datasets that can be used to train classifier through Google.

Who could tell me some free Chinese Named Entity Labeled datasets or free Chinese NER system? Any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the ACE corpora distributed by LDC (free only if you are an LDC member). Their website is http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/

Answer (score 1):

A Chinese NER model was added to Stanford NER starting with version 1.2.7 (released 2012-11-11).